# Xcode 5 Documentation window can't be made full-screen

Tags: xcode5

Xcode 5 Documentation window can't be made full-screen. Is this a bug or is there configuration that I need to enable? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a behavior of Xcode (albeit a stupid one). You should go onto Apple's developer portal and file a bug/feature request if it bothers you. I'm fairly certain that there's no configuration setting or such, so this is the only way it'll be added.